# Should I merge multiple target bins into one for better results?

Tags: python, multiclass-classification

I have a **multiclass classification** task where the **target** has **11 different classes**. The target to classify is the **Length of Stay** in a hospital and the target classes are in different bins, for example, `1-10`, `11-20`, `21-30` and so. So far I have tried **Neural Net** for my task but I am not getting a good performance.

Now I read this statement on Kaggle that decreasing the bins of the target i.e. instead of 11 classes **merge 2 or more classes into 1** so that I have less no of classes, might help in improving the model performance. Basically the more the number of classes, the worse your model performs. My question is, **Will decreasing the number of classes improve my model performance? Is it advisable to do so in real world datasets?**

Comment: Why are you predicting the bin instead of the value? This looks like a regression problem, not classification and maybe not even ordinal regression.

Comment: Can you expand on your statement? I am failing to understand how can it be a regression problem?

Comment: Predict “7” instead of “bin 1-10”.

Comment: Ok so assign an integer to each bins. Which is nothing but Label Encoding the target which we often do in Classification problems.

Comment: Predict the value within the bin. If the correct value is “7”, try to predict “7”. If the correct value is “2”, try to predict “2”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, yes: decreasing the number of classes mechanically increases the probability that the classifier finds the right one. Even in the worst case scenario where the class is picked randomly, the probability of every remaining class increases when there's one less class. Another way to look at it: all other things equal, the number of errors can only decrease when two classes are merged.

Whether it's advisable is a different matter. It's completely artificial: the performance may be higher but only because the problem is made easier. So it might look better on paper, but it's not in any way a real improvement. Additionally it would rarely cause a large performance increase unless a large number of classes are removed. Normally the decision should be made only because it makes sense for the task.

Finally I think that in this case this is not the right question: this task should probably be designed as a regression problem, not a classification one. The target ranges are ordinal, so a regression model should be able to make a better use of the information with a continuous target variable. For example each range could be represented as the mean: 5 for 1-10, 15 for 10-20, etc. If needed the predicted value can be mapped back to a range at the end of the process.

Also my usual advice is to start with a simple model first, for instance decision tree or SVM regression (SVR).

Comment: Ok if I map the bins to their mean, even then I would have 11 classes (1 for each bin). This is the same as label encoding the bins resulting in 11 different integers. In your case, other than the mean values obtained for each class, no other value would be possible. So ultimately it would be a classification problem with 11 integers as the target classes.

Comment: @spectre no, what I'm suggesting is not only to represent the class as an integer but to use a [regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) algorithm instead of a [classification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification) algorithm. This is completely different because in the case of classification the algorithm learns to distinguish between the classes, whereas in the case of regression it learns a continuous target.

Comment: Ok so what you are saying is that label encode the 11 bins resulting in target values of 0,1,2...10 and then apply a Regression algorithm?

Comment: Technically the term "label encoding" applies only to classification as far as I know (since the goal is to use an integer as a label), here it's just converting the range to a numerical value. But yes, that's the same idea.

Comment: But as you mention in your previous comment, regression model is used for continuous target. But in my case, the target is discrete, not continuous.

Comment: @spectre the main reason to use regression is that the variable is ordinal: it's expected that there's more similarity between 1-10 and 11-20 than between 1-10 and 21-30 for example. Classification with a categorical variable cannot take this order into account. You're right that the variable is discrete and that regression would consider it as continuous, but it's simple to re-discretize the continuous prediction at the end.

Comment: I tried using a regression model. Basically I mapped each target bin to integers an then trained a regression algorithm on it. When I predict on test data, the output is in float like 3.242, 5.848 and so on. How do I interpret this result as I had mapped my target bins to integers and my model is predicting float?

Comment: @spectre you can map the float output back to bins: for example 3.242 belongs to range 1-10, 27.401 belongs to range 20-30 and so on.

Comment: Kindly correct me if I am wrong. I have mapped the target bins as `1-10` as `0`, `11-20` as `1`, `21-30` as `2` and so on. So if my model predicts any value between `0.0` and `0.9` then I should map it to the bin `1-10`, if output is between `1.0` and `1.9` then it should be mapped to `11-20` and so on. Did I understand that correct?

Comment: @spectre I think that this is not the best option because when the model will predict say 0.7, it means that the instance is predicted between 0 (range 1-10) and 1 (11-20) but closer to the second range. So if you use these integer values you should probably map back to the range like this: v < 0.5 to 1-10,  0.5<v<1.5 to 11-20, etc. Or you can avoid this problem by using the mean of the range as target value (as I said in my answer), it's equivalent but the predicted values are more directly interpretable.

Comment: So `1-10` will be represented as `5`, `11-20` as `15.5`, `21-30` as `25.5`. Gotcha! But the part I'm not getting is how do I map the continuous values given by the model back to the bins?

Comment: @spectre this methods makes it straightforward:  if $v<11$ then map to 1-10, if $11 \leq v<21$ then map to 11-20, if $21 \leq v<31$ then map to 21-30, etc. Note that it's possible that in some rare cases the predicted values goes lower than 1 (maybe even lower than 0) or higher than your max range.